# How to detect bottom of UITextView (UIScrollView) glitch in iOS

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uitextview

I am working on a lazy loader and I'm into an issue where my `UITextView` thinks it's at the bottom of the view immediately after I load more data, consequently incorrectly setting my offsets.

I'm just trying to load the new data, and have the `UITextView` scroll down slightly so the user is aware more data has been loaded.

**CODE:**

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
  float scrollViewHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
  float scrollContentSizeHeight = scrollView.contentSize.height;
  float yOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
  NSLog(@"yOffset + scrollViewHeight = %f",yOffset + scrollViewHeight);
  NSLog(@"yOffset = %f",yOffset );

  if (yOffset == 0) {
    // then we are at the top
  }
  else if (yOffset + scrollViewHeight == scrollContentSizeHeight) {
    if (self.updateInProgress) {
      NSLog(@"updateInProgress");
      return;
    }
    // then we are at the end
    self.updateInProgress = TRUE;
    NSLog(@"scrollContentSizeHeight = %f",scrollView.contentSize.height);
    NSLog(@" === at bottom of scrollview ===");

    // JUST NEED TO FIX WHERE SCROLLVIEW APPEARS!
    self.TextView.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n%@",self.TextView.text, self.nextChapterString];
    CGPoint offset = self.TextView.contentOffset;
    offset.y = yOffset + scrollViewHeight + 100;
    [self.TextView setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
    //NSLog(@"updated TextView = %@", self.TextView.text);
    // since disabled scrolling while updating, force scroll down a bit
    //    CGPoint offset = scrollView.contentOffset;
    //    offset.y += 100;
    //    [scrollView setContentOffset:offset animated:YES];

  }
  self.updateInProgress = FALSE;
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

This is the output I see, where as you can see, my yOffset changes drastically after more data is loaded...

```
2014-05-07 23:11:40.370 Test[6314:60b] yOffset + scrollViewHeight = 1821.500000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.370 Test[6314:60b] yOffset = 1432.500000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.371 Test[6314:60b] yOffset = 389.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.403 Test[6314:60b] yOffset + scrollViewHeight = 1821.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.403 Test[6314:60b] yOffset = 1432.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.404 Test[6314:60b] yOffset = 389.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.470 Test[6314:60b] yOffset + scrollViewHeight = 1820.500000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.471 Test[6314:60b] yOffset = 1431.500000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.471 Test[6314:60b] yOffset = 389.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.504 Test[6314:60b] yOffset + scrollViewHeight = 1820.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.505 Test[6314:60b] yOffset = 1431.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.505 Test[6314:60b] yOffset = 389.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.506 Test[6314:60b] scrollContentSizeHeight = 1820.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.506 Test[6314:60b]  === at bottom of scrollview ===
2014-05-07 23:11:40.508 Test[6314:60b] yOffset + scrollViewHeight = 2309.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.508 Test[6314:60b] yOffset = 1920.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.508 Test[6314:60b] yOffset = 389.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.509 Test[6314:60b] yOffset + scrollViewHeight = 1954.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.509 Test[6314:60b] yOffset = 1565.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.510 Test[6314:60b] yOffset = 389.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.510 Test[6314:60b] scrollContentSizeHeight = 1954.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.510 Test[6314:60b]  === at bottom of scrollview ===
2014-05-07 23:11:40.512 Test[6314:60b] yOffset + scrollViewHeight = 2443.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.512 Test[6314:60b] yOffset = 2054.000000
2014-05-07 23:11:40.513 Test[6314:60b] yOffset = 389.000000
```

Any suggestions as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
    text.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\n%@",text.text, str];
    CGPoint offset = text.contentOffset;
    offset.y = yOffset + scrollViewHeight + 100;
    text.delegate = nil;//set your delegate nil
    [text setContentOffset:offset animated:NO];
    text.delegate = self;//set back
```